# New Managed Path before a site collection

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, collections, path, managed

I already created a top level Web Application and site collection. 
The powershell input for my site collection is.

```
Get-SPWebTemplate | Where{ $_.Title -eq "Team Site" } | ForEach-Object{ New-SPSite http://teampowershell.sharepoint1c.lab -OwnerAlias SHAREPOINT1C\SP_FARM -Template $_ }
```

After this I am attempting to create a new top level site at the URL.

> "http://teams.contoso.com/Finance" with the powershell command

```
Get-SPWebTemplate | Where{ $_.Title -eq "Team Site" } | ForEach-Object{ New-SPSite http://teampowershell.sharepoint1c.lab/finance -OwnerAlias SHAREPOINT1C\SP_FARM -Template $_ }
```

but I am greeted with this error

```
>"New-SPSite : A site collection could not be created as the provided managed pat
h does not exist.  Change the URL to use an existing managed path or create the
 missing managed path prior to calling this command.
At line:1 char:83
+ Get-SPWebTemplate | Where{ $_.Title -eq "Team Site" } | ForEach-Object{ New-S
PSite <<<<  http://teampowershell.sharepoint1c.lab/finance -OwnerAlias SHAREPOI
NT1C\SP_FARM -Template $_ }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:
   SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite], SPCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite"
```

I assume I have to create a managed path but where do I specify a managed SiteCollectionURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you would through Central Admin, you don't specify the site collection but rather the the web app under which the [managed path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx) will live:

```
New-SPManagedPath [-RelativeURL] "</RelativeURL>" -WebApplication <WebApplication>
```